# Understanding the structure of つもりです

Tags: grammar

I just learned a phrase `つもりです` which can be used to express `plan to do something`. For example, `来月、日本へ旅行に行くつもりです`　and  `私は結婚しないつもりだ`.

But what confuses me is the structure of the sentence,
`日本へ旅行に行く` is basically describing the verb `行く`. `つもり` is an noun, so the structure is `verb + noun + です`, but for most sentences I have learned so far, the core structure can be divided into `verb [+ます/ません/ました..]` or `noun + だ/です/...`. This `行くつもりです` looks weird.

So my question is, is this a specific structure or my understanding of basic structures is wrong?

Comment: Did you mean つ**も**り rather than つ**ま**り?

Comment: Ooops. It should be つもり. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a specific structure, you probably didn't learn yet the fundamental structure of "relative clause". https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48844/are-relative-clauses-used-differently-in-japanese

Comment: Does this help, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17797/9831

Comment: @ThomasPetit I know some relative clause structure like `日本へ行ったこと`, so here `行く` is a relative clause of `つもり`? Sounds reasonable..

Comment: This kind of structure is very common, and even more complicated structures are common. Not everything is です and ます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative clauses in Japanese are much simpler than those in English, so noun-based expressions in the form `verb + noun` is extremely common in Japanese.

- お腹が空いている**はず**です。
  you *must* be hungry
- 言われる**まま**に支払った。
  I paid as I was told to.
- 旅行に行く**とき**
  *when* [someone] travels
- 本を読んだ**ため**
  *because* [someone] read the book

These weird "nouns" are collectively called 形式名詞 ("formal noun"). つもり is one of them.

Related:

- [冗談のつもり the grammatical explanation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69532/5010)
- [ダンスの先生なんだから、上手なはずですよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69446/5010)